# Entity Framework Core use take on include without loading all data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

this is my query

```
var geometrias = _context.Geometrias
                    .Include(g => g.GeometriaRegistos)
                    .Include(g => g.Matriz)
                    .ThenInclude(m => m.Referencia)
                    .Where(g => g.Matriz.ReferenciaId == referenciaId && !g.IsDeleted && !g.Matriz.IsDeleted)
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Id)
                    .Take(20)
                    .ToList();
```

i would like to get only 20 GeometriaRegistos per Geometria

but

```
.Include(g => g.GeometriaRegistos.Take(20))
```

does not work

here are the models

```
public class GeometriaRegisto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public float X1 { get; set; }
    public float X2 { get; set; }
    public float X3 { get; set; }
    public float X4 { get; set; }

    public int GeometriaId { get; set; }
    public Geometria Geometria { get; set; }

    public int ProducaoRegistoId { get; set; }
    public ProducaoRegisto ProducaoRegisto { get; set; }
}

public class Geometria
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Componente { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public int MatrizId { get; set; }
    public Matriz Matriz { get; set; }

    public ICollection<GeometriaRegisto> GeometriaRegistos { get; set; }
}
```

I used to do this with Dapper and SQL stored procedure and i'm trying to use linq to manage this but i cannot find a way to do it without having to load all of them on memory first and then filter again but it's a lot of data

Comment: Yes i only want to load 20 rows per Geometria

Comment: Last time I checked, EF Core didn't support subqueries and instead fetched all data from an `Include` before filtering at a software level, instead of filtering at the database. Somebody please correct me if I'm wrong, this was when EF Core first came out.

Comment: Correct. `Include` has always been: everything. No filtering, no sorting, no nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this scenario is not supported.

When you `.Include` you're actually signaling that you desire the `JOIN` of the relationship.

In order to achieve what you desire, i'd recommend you to fetch all yours `Geometrias` without including `GeometriasRegistros`. Then select the ids you will fetch like `grIds = geometrias.Select(g=>g.GeometriasRegistros.Take(20).Id).Distinct()`. Next step is to query based on these Ids and to wrap-it, just populate your collection manually...

not a work of art, but will work